# Can you format the legend so that each value shows two colors in Tableau?

Tags: format, tableau-api, legend

I have a set of data that has both 2018 and 2019 data.  I made a bar chart in Tableau from the data and it has split the columns by month, then by year. Each column was then color-coded according to possible values of the chosen attribute.

Then, I also made the 2019 colors slightly brighter than the 2018 colors.  I did that by dragging the attribute and date into "color" at the same time.

The problem, however, is that the legend now shows a very long list of color-codes based on both the attribute value and the year.  Since both years have the same attribute values, is there a way to just display each of the attribute values once with two colors for each of the years?

The bar chart is set up like this:

x----|----x|-----|
x----|x---x|----x|
x---x|x---x|----x|
x---x|x---x|x---x|
18 19|18 19|18 19|
-Jan-|-Feb-|-Mar-|

Where the x's represent the bar.  Hopefully you can kind of understand that - it makes more sense when it's aligned.

Currently in the legend I have:

color1a value1 - 2018
color1b value1 - 2019
color2a value2 - 2018
color2b value2 - 2019
color3a value3 - 2018
color3b value3 - 2019
...

What I want is:

color1a color1b value1
color2a color2b value2
color3a color3b value3
...

Let me know if there's anything I can clarify.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot?  Might be easier to visualize.

Comment: Your best bet for a custom legend like this might be to make your own legend as a sheet and present both sheets on a dashboard.